# How to detect active java version (32bits oder 64 bits) in a batch file

Tags: java, windows, batch-file

I must include in a batch file a test regarding the OS architecture and the Java architecture in order to define the appropriate memory parameter (-Xmx).

OS detection is OK ( we test on SysW64:

```
    IF EXIST %WINDIR%\SysWOW64\
    SET MDM_MEMORY=-Xmx4096m
    ) ELSE (
    SET MDM_MEMORY=-Xmx900m
)
```

But now I want to add further test on the Java version (32 or 64 bits).
Some clients have Java installed (in the Registry), some others have a Java located on the disk, and the program refers to it.

So I want to be sure that:

1. I do locate the active Java, not the one from the Registry if it is not used by my program
2. I want to identify the architecture, but not from the path to the Java bin, or some name since:

   - some customer have Java installed in C:\SomePath\Jre1.7 (no mention of the arch)

I tried looking for the path, and also using java -version, but I am stuck here

The result is to define a memory parameter -Xmx for windows 32 bits, windows 64 with Java 32, and finally with Windows64 bist / Java 64 bits.

Ideally, I will add a message that says "Java 32 bist detected, this will lead to poorer performance, please consider upgrading to Java 64 bits"

PS: you have noticed that I am not a developer, I am using the base of former colleagues. Thanks for your patience

Comment: execute `java -version` and analyse the result to detect the version

Comment: Your question seems to be asking about an 'active java', but it appears that your intention is to define options for running that 'java'. Can you please clarify your task.

Comment: You could do this: `java -d64 -version 2>nul && (echo 64-bit) || (echo 32-bit)`. Alternatively, you could follow @XtremeBaumer's advice, taking into account that `java -version` returns the output at _STDERR_ rather than _STDOUT_. For detecting whether the OS is 64-bit or 32-bit take a look at [this resource](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-64bit.html)...

Comment: Hi @Compo, and the others too. The difference between active and installed: some users are working with a Java that they have installed, and others with another Java installation besides the installed one. The latter can have as answer to the quey the arch of the installed java, or the arch to the java they are really using and that is located anywhere on their disk. That is why I really want to be sure that the active java is tested. I hope I made my point clear.

Comment: There's nothing to stop any user from using a 32bit version on a x64 PC, or having multiple versions both 'installed' or 'portable'. There's also no guarantee that any of those will reside within a location under %PATH% or have the defined environment variables necessary for their direct use. Your question requires a proper edit to clarify a specific issue with your code, otherwise it is off topic.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following to determine the ARCH of the JVM in batch file

```
@echo off
java -d32 -version >NUL 2>&1
if %errorlevel%==0 (echo 32 bit JVM detected, this will lead to poorer performance, please consider upgrading to Java 64 bit JVM) else (echo 64 bit JVM detected)
```